# How do I validate the user response within a function and return to the main program once a valid response is given?

Tags: bash

I need to validate a series user entries that requires A or B, Y or No, etc like responses. I would like to validate that the entered value is validated to the allowed set of responses. Wrote a function to perform each validation with their respective requirements. Function appears to work but I can't break out of the main loop once the response is satisfactory.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
function valcheck()
{
while true;
do
  if [[ "$response" =~ [$1] ]]
  then
    echo "Acceptible response"
    return 0
  else
    echo "Invalid response!"
    continue
  fi
  done
}

#call function
printf "What is the response [A/P]: "
while true; do
  read -r response
  valcheck "AaPp"
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to have two `while` loops.
Also, I am not a fan of `while true` loops.
You can reduce the reading an validating of user input to one function:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

valcheck() {
    while
        printf '%s' "$2"
        read -r response
    do
        if
            [[ "$response" =~ ^[$1]$ ]]
        then
            echo "Acceptable response!"
            break
        else
            echo "Invalid response!"
        fi
    done
}

valcheck "AaPp" "What is the response [A/P]: "
```

Comment: This works perfectly, however, here is a follow-up:  I need to load the resulting "good" answer into the parameter for the specific question.
original question:   printf "what is A/P"; read -r response_for_AB
we now have: valcheck "AP" "what is A/P"
but how to I load the response to my variable in question?  How do I load the validated answer into response_for_AB?

Comment: I mean how do I do something to the effect:  
response_for_AP = valcheck "AP" "what is A/P" which should ideally load the validated value back into the variable.

Comment: Perhaps: `response_for_AP="$(valcheck "AP" "What is A/P")"`. @Gordon

Comment: Thanks.  That made sense but when I try it:
While this alternative works:
 valcheck "What is the response [A/P]: " "AP"; app_type="$response"
This one just sits there with no response: 
app_type="$(valcheck "What is the response [A/P]: " "AP")"
($response is the returned validated value from the call)

Comment: Whoops, my mistake, the function will try to read from a closed input descriptor inside the subshell created by `$(...)`.  Just add `app_type=$response` after the execution of `valcheck` and you will get the correct answer in the variable `app_type` (even if it is already in `response` and you could use that variable.

Comment: Yes, that alternative works fine.  I was just hoping to tidy up the thing with a format of:
app_type = valcheck("What is A/P", "AaPP", "response")  which is a bit tidier if all possible.  I am perfectly fine with the extra assignment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The command word you're looking for is `break` to exit the `while true` loop when your subroutine returns success:

```
valcheck "AaPp" && break
```

As a side note, you may want to move your prompt `printf` command inside the loop.  When the response isn't "a" or "p", then it's a little nicer to the user to ask again for the answer you want.